# Reviewing Probabilities and Bayes Rule

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I am reviewing probabilites and I have a couple of questions that have come up... I have attempted answers and will share my thinking but I am stuck in a couple of places and would like some confirmations/ guiding.

1. Events A, B, C in a sample space have $P(A) = 0.2$, $P(B)= 0.4$ and $ P(A \cup B \cup C) = 0.9.$ Find $P(C)$ if A and C are mutually exclusive, A and B are independent and B and C are independent. 
   Here is how I started: 
   $$P(A\cup B\cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap B)- P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$$
   Substituing knows and $P(A \cap C) = O$ since mutually exclusive and $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(B\cap C)$ since independent. 
   $$ 0.9 = 0.2 + 0.4 + P(C) - (0.2 \cdot 0.4) - 0 - 0.4P(C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$$
   $$ .22 = 0.6 P(C) + P(A \cap B\cap C)$$ is as far as I can get down to and I am not sure where to go. How do I figure out $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ without C but know the other things about the events?
2. A parts store sells both new and used parts.  60% of the parts in stock are used.  61% are used or defective.  If 5% of the store's parts are defective what percentage are both used and defective?

For this one I tried to create a table but I am not sure how to fill in new and defective, new and non-defective or used and non-defective. What can I do?

Comment: (1) $P(A\cap B \cap C)=0$ for  $A$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I wondered if that was true... any other suggestions? I know this is pretty basic but just dusting out the cobwebs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As far as (1)**

The key is that  $A\cap C=\emptyset\ \rightarrow P(A\cap B\cap C)=0.$

**As far as (2)**

In general: $P(U \cup D)=P(U)+P(D)-P(U \cap D).$ So
$$P(U \cap D)=-P(U \cup D)+P(U)+P(D)=-0.61+0.6+0.05=0.49.$$